# Como consultar una query que arroja 3 filas por cada fila en otra tabla

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de hacer una query que me regrese las 3 competencias mas altas de cada alumno que hay en la tabla alumno, despues tengo agruparlo por competencia y contarlas, pero no logro primero obtener una query donde obtenga las 3 competencias mas altas de todos los estudiantes, ahora mismo tengo esta query:

```
SELECT * FROM competenciaEstudiante c_e
LEFT JOIN competencia c
ON c.id_competencia = c_e.competencia
WHERE estudiante = 1 AND c.tipo="algo" ORDER BY porcentaje DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Esta query me regresa las 3 competencias mas altas del estudiante con el ID 1, pero lo que quiero es que por cada estudiante me de las 3 filas en una sola query, despues le añadire mas filtros.
Intente la siguiente query:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT c_e.porcentaje FROM competenciaEstudiante c_e
LEFT JOIN competencia c
ON c.id_competencia = c_e.competencia
WHERE c_e.estudiante = e.id_estudiante AND c.tipo="algo" ORDER BY c_e.porcentaje DESC LIMIT 1) AS porcentaje FROM estudiante e;
```

Pero tiene la limitacion de que de esta forma solo me arroja 1 sola fila por alumno, cuando quiero las 3 primeras de cada alumno, intente algunas otras querys tambien pero hasta ahora esta es la que mas *"cerca"* ha estado.

Edit: Olvide mencionar que esto es en mysql 5.6, la respuesta de nachospiu seria la ideal pero lamentablemente no tengo funciones de ventana, ahora quiero hacer la consulta de una forma diferente:

Quiero hacer varias querys, cada una es mas o menos la misma, simplemente cambiaria un numero:
Necesito obtener todas las competencias y contar cuales estan en el primer lugar de los estudiantes, tengo esta query:

```
SELECT ce.*, (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num FROM competenciaEstudiante ce INNER JOIN competencia c 
            ON ce.competencia=c.id_competencia AND ce.competencia_nombre=c.nombre, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
  WHERE c.lista=3 AND c.tipo="miPerfil" and ce.estudiante=34
ORDER BY porcentaje DESC;
```

Que me trae las competencias de un estudiante ordenadas de mayor a menor y enumeradas.
Despues tengo esta otra query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT ce.*, (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num FROM competenciaEstudiante ce INNER JOIN competencia c 
            ON ce.competencia=c.id_competencia AND ce.competencia_nombre=c.nombre, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
  WHERE c.lista=3 AND c.tipo="miPerfil" AND ce.estudiante=34
ORDER BY porcentaje DESC) AS competenciasOrdenadas WHERE num=1;
```

Que me trae la competencia numero 1 de un estudiante en particular.

Esas dos querys funcionan, pero no he logrado traer todas las competencias y contar cuantos alumnos la tienen en primer, segundo o tercer lugar (Para cada lugar seria una consulta diferente). Como mencione la respuesta de nachospiu seria la ideal para estos casos tambien, pero lamentablemente no cuento con funciones de ventana.

Export de las tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE `competencia` (
  `id_competencia` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` text,
  `tipo` enum('miPerfil','miVocacion') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_competencia`,`nombre`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_competencia` (`id_competencia`,`nombre`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `competenciaEstudiante` (
  `estudiante` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `competencia` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `competencia_nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `esFortaleza` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `porcentaje` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`estudiante`,`competencia`,`competencia_nombre`),
  KEY `competencia` (`competencia`,`competencia_nombre`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `estudiante` (
  `id_estudiante` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_aplicacion` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_estudiante`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `competenciaEstudiante`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Constr_competenciaEstudiante_estudiante_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`estudiante`) REFERENCES `estudiante` (`id_estudiante`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `competenciaEstudiante_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`competencia`,`competencia_nombre`) REFERENCES `competencia` (`id_competencia`, `nombre`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Conviene que en las preguntas sobre bases de datos agregues un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable con los `CREATE TABLE` y los INSERT (incluyendo un fiddle si es posible) de modo que se pueda verificar con mayor facilidad el código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no cuentas con funciones de ventana puedes crear un conjunto (set) de las competencias más altas con `group_concat()` agrupando por alumno en una subsconsulta. En la consulta principal simplemente para cada competencia cuentas el número de ocurrencias en la subconsulta y al ordenar descendentemente te limitas a las primeras 3.

```
SELECT c.id_competencia
     , c.nombre
     , count(1) conteo
  FROM ( SELECT estudiante
              , group_concat(competencia ORDER BY porcentaje desc)
              , substring_index( group_concat(competencia ORDER BY porcentaje desc)
                               , ','
                               , 3
                               ) top
           FROM competenciaEstudiante
           GROUP BY estudiante
       ) t
    INNER JOIN competencia c
      ON find_in_set(c.id_competencia,t.top)
  GROUP BY c.id_competencia, c.nombre
  ORDER BY conteo desc
  LIMIT 3
```

Nota: En la tabla `competencias` incluir `nombre` en la llave primaria sería incorrecto cuando -parece ser- quieres que el nombre sea único, y en el mismo sentido `id_competencia` sobra en el `UNIQUE`:

```
  PRIMARY KEY (id_competencia),
  UNIQUE KEY unombre (nombre)
```

Para la consulta de la edición el `find_in_set()` te da el lugar:

```
SELECT c.id_competencia
     , c.nombre
     , count(1) conteo
     , find_in_set(c.id_competencia,t.top) lugar
  FROM ( SELECT estudiante
              , group_concat(competencia ORDER BY porcentaje desc)
              , substring_index( group_concat(competencia ORDER BY porcentaje desc)
                               , ','
                               , 3
                               ) top
           FROM competenciaEstudiante
           GROUP BY estudiante
       ) t
    INNER JOIN competencia c
      ON find_in_set(c.id_competencia,t.top)
  GROUP BY c.id_competencia, c.nombre, lugar
  ORDER BY conteo desc
```

El resultado lo leerías como:
"La competencia `<nombre>` es `<conteo>` veces `<lugar>` lugar".

Comment: Es util cuando trato de obtener las primeras 3, pero cuando quiero obtener las querys diferentes del edit no he podido adaptarla

Comment: Gracias! No sabia como funcionaba el find_in_set(), como seria si quiero traer incluso las que tengan 0 en conteo y que digamos por ejemplo "La competencia <nombre> es 0 veces <lugar> lugar"? Trate de hacerlo con un IFNULL() pero no lo logre

Comment: Prueba con `RIGHT JOIN competencia c`.

Comment: Gracias! Me sirvio genial la query para esta version de mysql

Comment: Como podria concatenar resultados lugares? De forma por ejemplo que la tabla me de:
[<competencia en el lugar 1> - <competencia en el lugar 2>] <conteo>

Entonces el resultado seria:
Las competencias <nombre1 - nombre2> la tienen tantos alumnos

Answer (score 1):

**MySql >= 8.0**

Para obtener las tres competencias mas altas por cada alumno, lo que puedes hacer es enumerar las competencias por cada alumno (comenzando desde 1 para cada alumno) ordenando por porcentaje DESC (el orden 1 sería para la competencia mas alta de cada alumno y la mas baja tendría el mayor número de orden para cada alumno); posteriormente filtras solo aquellas competencias con orden <= 3.

```
WITH competenciasOrdenadas AS (SELECT *,
                                      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ce.estudiante ORDER BY ce.porcentaje DESC) AS orden
                               FROM competenciaEstudiante ce
                               INNER JOIN competencia c ON c.id_competencia = ce.competencia
                               WHERE c.tipo = "algo")
                                           
SELECT *
FROM competenciasOrdenadas
WHERE orden <= 3;
```

Luego puedes agrupar las competencias resultantes y contarlas:

```
WITH competenciasOrdenadas AS (SELECT *,
                                      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ce.estudiante ORDER BY ce.porcentaje DESC) AS orden
                               FROM competenciaEstudiante ce
                               INNER JOIN competencia c ON c.id_competencia = ce.competencia
                               WHERE c.tipo = "algo")
                              
SELECT id_competencia, count(*)
FROM competenciasOrdenadas
WHERE orden <= 3
GROUP BY id_competencia;
```

**MySql 5.6**

Siguiendo la misma lógica, en MySql 5.6 lo puedes implementar de la siguiente forma.

Tienes que tener en cuenta que el número de fila (orden) debe comenzar desde uno para cada estudiante, y así obtienes las tres competencias con mayor porcentaje para cada estudiante.

```
SELECT id_competencia, count(*)
FROM (SELECT 
       sq1.*,
       
       @row_number:=CASE WHEN @estudiante = sq1.estudiante THEN @row_number + 1 ELSE 1 END AS orden,
       @estudiante:= sq1.estudiante

       FROM (SELECT *
             FROM competenciaEstudiante ce
             INNER JOIN competencia c ON c.id_competencia = ce.competencia
             WHERE c.tipo = "algo"
             ORDER BY ce.estudiante ASC, ce.porcentaje DESC) AS sq1) AS sq2
WHERE orden <= 3    
GROUP BY id_competencia;
```

Comment: Esta query seria perfecta, pero lamentablemente no tengo funciones de ventana porque la version de mysql es 5.6, me falto mencionar eso.

Comment: @Jugo edité mi respuesta y agregué una solución para MySql 5.6 siguiendo la misma lógica. Es importante que al preguntar siempre especifiqués la versión que estás utilizando, porque como en este caso la solución puede ser distinta de acuerdo a la versión utilizada. Cuando la respuesta no es la esperada o no soluciona tu problema puedes interactuar con quien respondió para aclarar donde estuvo el problema.